# ORDER BY Date - Realm (Android)

Tags: android, realm

I've a column/field called `last_message_time` of type `Date` in my Table A.
Suppose querying Table A returns `x` results.
How do i sort these results based on dates inside `last_message_time` column.

Example, in SQLite we have  `ORDER BY date(dateColumn)`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
RealmResults<A> sorted = realm.where(A.class)
                              .findAllSorted("last_message_time", Sort.ASCENDING);
```

**EDIT:** since Realm 4.3.0, the following is preferred:

```
RealmResults<A> sorted = realm.where(A.class)
                              .sort("last_message_time", Sort.ASCENDING) 
                              .findAll();
```

Comment: Hey Zhuinden, I have a question on realm's Time Complexity in sort operation can you please help me it would be really helpful for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64362606/is-time-complexity-of-findfirst-after-sort-in-realm-is-on-if-the-field-is-n

Answer (score 3):

Use just "sort"!
"findAllSorted" is deprecated!

> io.realm.RealmQuery.findAllSorted(String)
>   Since 4.3.0, now use RealmQuery.sort(String) then RealmQuery.findAll() Finds all objects that fulfill the query conditions and sorted by specific field name in ascending order.
>   Sorting is currently limited to character sets in 'Latin Basic', 'Latin Supplement', 'Latin Extended A', 'Latin Extended B' (UTF-8 range 0-591). For other character sets, sorting will have no effect.

More details in: [LINK](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#findAllSorted-java.lang.String-)