# Is Time complexity of findFirst() after sort in Realm is O(n), If the field is not indexed?

Tags: android, realm

In Realm is the Time complexity of `findFirst()` after `sort` always O(n) ? If the field is not indexed, Because if it is optimizing it's query then it should be O(n) ?

Comment: Find nth element in an array is always O(n) either sorted or not sorted.

Comment: @Mr.AF nth TIme complexity in sort cant be O(n) as it will have to perform sort for all n items then only it can give us the nth item.

Comment: sort complexity is not always O(n) and depend on sorting algorithm , it can be O(n^2) or O(nLogn) .

Comment: I am talking about Find or Search which is in best case is always O(n)

Comment: That's why I am saying it always matters if I am performing sort or not.

Comment: @Mr.AF TimeComplexity always assumes it is worst case, that's why I am asking for the worst case in my question.

Comment: if you perform counting sort , the its complexity is O(n) and for best case Find is O(n) so it depend on you if you want to sort or just find

Comment: I want to perform sort and then find first because then even in worst case scenario it can be O(n).

Comment: So do perform Counting Sort in O(n) and Find the nth element in O(1)

Comment: what is counting sort ? Can you tell me any documentation on that.

Comment: Search this book `Introduction_to_algorithms-3rd Edition`

Comment: But still how can realm sort in O(n) ? If the field is not indexed.